# data type in sql query

Tags: mysql, database

My sql query is as follows :

```
SELECT (pass*100)/total as result from Runs where runId=1
```

I want result to be of decimal type. I tried :

```
SELECT 
cast((pass*100)/total as decimal(4,2)) as result 
from Runs where runId=1
```

I am using the value returned by this query in a computation so I have done :

```
protected decimal d1;
decimal.TryParse(reader["result"].ToString(), out d1);
```

but d1 has value 83 when it should have 83.4

Comment: What are the types of the pass and total columns?

Comment: please clarify "doesn't work" - an error? or integer returned?

Comment: pass and total are int

Comment: Try simply replacing `100` with `100.0`.

Comment: @Marcus - Brilliant ! It works :) I feel so silly to not have thought of it.Please write it as an answer so that I can mark it correct. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast at least one of the arguments as floating point, otherwise all of the math will be done as integer math.

Probably the easiest solution is to convert the constant to a floating point value by changing `100` to `100.0`:

```
SELECT (pass*100.0)/total as result from Runs where runId=1
```

Even if you didn't have a constant to leverage in your calculation, it's easier (less typing) to cast an integer like this rather than using `CAST()`:

```
SELECT int_col1 * 1.0 / int_col2 AS result FROM table1
```

Comment: Return type is a floating point not decimal. Perhaps cast the result to a decimal in MySQL or do it in code if you are assigning to decimal type.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT 
(1pass* cast(100 as decimal(4,2))/total ) as result 
from Runs where runId=1
```

Comment: why have u divided by 5 ?

Comment: @user1698232 sorry was a copy from my test.